# Controlling file upload location in Google Drive (App script not form)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script

I'm implementing Kanshi Tanaike's [Resumable Upload For Web Apps](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps) code and it works, but I don't fully understand the AJAX and am trying add a feature. Right now the code places the new file in the user's Drive root folder. I would either like to define a specific folder and upload there directly, or automatically move the file from root to the correct folder (I also need to collect the download link). I see the upload function references location in the response header, but I'm struggling to figure out how to define it, and since the doUpload() function does not seem to treat the upload as a File object I can't figure out how to reference it after the upload to acquire the URL or move it. Any feedback would be enormously appreciated.

```
  $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (file.name != "") {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.fileName = file.name;
        fr.fileSize = file.size;
        fr.fileType = file.type;
        fr.onload = init;
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});

function init() {
    $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
    var fileName = this.fileName;
    var fileSize = this.fileSize;
    var fileType = this.fileType;
    console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
    var buf = this.result;
    var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
    var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
        return {
            data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
            length: e.numByte,
            range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
        };
    });
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            mimeType: fileType,
            name: fileName,
        }));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            doUpload({
                location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                chunks: chunks,
            });
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        };
    }).getAt();
}

function doUpload(e) {
    var chunks = e.chunks;
    var location = e.location;
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = chunks.length;
    var temp = function callback(cnt) {
        var e = chunks[cnt];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
        xhr.send(e.data);
        xhr.onloadend = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            cnt += 1;
            console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
            $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
            if (status == 308) {
                callback(cnt);
            } else if (status == 200) {
                $("#progress").text("Done.");
            } else {
                $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
            }
        };
    }(cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to upload a file to the specific folder.
- You want to retrieve `webContentLink` of the uploaded file.
- You want to achieve above using [Resumable Upload for Web Apps using Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps)
- You have already confirmed that the default script at the repository worked.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to check [the resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) and [the method of "Files: create"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) in Drive API.

  - In order to upload the file to the specific folder, please add the folder ID to the request body of the initial request.
  - In order to return the value of `webContentLink`, please use `fields` value to the initial request.

When above points are reflected to the original script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, [HTML](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps/blob/master/index.html) is modified.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Resumable upload for Web Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

<script>
    const chunkSize = 5242880;

    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            fr.onload = init;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    });

    function init() {
        var folderId = "###";  // Added: Please set the folder ID.
    
        $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
        var fileName = this.fileName;
        var fileSize = this.fileSize;
        var fileType = this.fileType;
        console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
        var buf = this.result;
        var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
                data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
                length: e.numByte,
                range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&fields=*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                mimeType: fileType,
                name: fileName,
                parents: [folderId]  // Added
            }));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                doUpload({
                    location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                    chunks: chunks,
                });
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.log(xhr.response);
            };
        }).getAt();
    }

    function doUpload(e) {
        var chunks = e.chunks;
        var location = e.location;
        var cnt = 0;
        var end = chunks.length;
        var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    var metadata = JSON.parse(xhr.response);  // Added
                    $("#progress").text("Done. Link: " + metadata.webContentLink);  // Modified
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                }
            };
        }(cnt);
    }

    function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

- When the above modified script is run, the uploaded file is created to the specific folder and `webContentLink` is displayed as the result.

#### References:

- [Perform a resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Resumable Upload for Web Apps using Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I tested and after some permissions errors it all works correctly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @gweintraub Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.